# Siamese network stuck at 50% accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to build a Siamese network to do re-identification, the final output of this network should be feature vectors that are compared in order to decide if the input images are from the same class or not. The accuracy of my model is stuck at 50%. I tried multiple variations in the loss function, accuracy and in the layers of the model, but nothing seems to be working and my knowledge in the area stops me from trying another approach. What could possibly resolve this problem?

```
def cnn(in_dims):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=(in_dims[0],in_dims[1],in_dims[2]),activation='relu',name='conv1'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool1'))

    model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',name='conv2'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool2'))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',name='conv3'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool3'))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu',name='conv4'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),(2,2),padding='same',name='pool4'))

    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    model.add(Dense(64,name='embeddings'))

    return model

def double_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    total_length = y_pred.shape.as_list()[-1]

    image1 = y_pred[:,0:int(total_length*1/2)]
    image2 = y_pred[:,int(total_length*1/2):int(total_length*2/2)]

    dist = K.sum(K.square(image1 - image2), axis=1)

    return dist

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.cast(y_pred < 0.5, y_true.dtype)))

input_1 = Input(shape=(128,64,3,), name='input_1')
input_2 = Input(shape=(128,64,3,), name = 'input_2')

shared = cnn([128,64,3])

encoded_image1 = shared(input_1)
encoded_image2 = shared(input_2)

merged_vector = concatenate([encoded_image1, encoded_image2], axis=-1, name='merged_layer')

model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=merged_vector)

model.compile(loss=double_loss, optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.0001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999), metrics=[accuracy])

history = model.fit([X_a_train, X_b_train], y=y_train,
                    batch_size=128, epochs=100, validation_data=[[X_a_val, X_b_val], y_val])
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you try to classify which number is shown in the pictures you provide. Therefore you should use as last layer in your network 10 Neurons (Numbers 0-9) and the activation function "softmax" (Gives the propability of each possible number so that the sum of the poropability is 1). This is also shown in the keras example [here](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/)

Comment: I was not clear enough, sorry. I have updated the question to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.